# What is the meaning of "offsetting" in this passage?

Tags: meaning

i am not english native speaker, i am italian.

*What is the meaning of "offsetting" in this passage?*

> The functioning of derivatives central counterparties hinges on the
>   enforceability of two legal processes:
>
> 1) Novation:  the replacement of the original contract between two
>   counterparties with two **offsetting** contracts between the original
>   counterparties and the Central Counterparty Clearing House.

Comment: The noun *i* is written *I*, uppercase.

Comment: Also capitalize language/nationality names (English, Italian).

Answer (score 2):

In a [Business Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/offset?q=offsetting) you can find this:

**offset:** to balance one effect against an opposing effect, so that there is no great difference as a result.

So, in this context, **offsetting contracts** means "contracts that balance each other" in a way that one contract represents the interests of one counterparty and the other represents the interests of another counterparty.